# PLC Ladder Logic - memory and processing management

Tags: memory-management, logic, plc

I am beginning with ladder programing and english is not my first language. A professor of mine once said that I could not put more than one output on a same ladder rung, is that correct? And if so, is it preferable to put the outputs on other rungs or on the same one to save memory space and processing time?

Comment: Could it be that the professor said "do not put the same output on more than one ladder rung" (slightly different wording)?  THAT IS good advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have yet to see a PLC that can't handle multiple outputs on same rung.

Like @franji1 said, he might have said **do not** and not **you can't**. I would never recommend to have multiple outputs on a rung, but sometimes it can be necessary.

He could also have told you to not have the same output in multiple rungs since the PLC would always read the last rung.

So let's say you activate O:1.0 in rung 1, but in rung 20 O:1.0 is not active, then this output will never turn on, since the PLC handels output after each full scan.

```
 AlwaysON       O:0.0
---[]-------------()

AlwaysOFF         O:0.0
---[]-------------()
```

Like her the last rung would never be true so O:0.0 will always be *false* even thought it is active in the earlier rung.

If you then swap the rungs around so the AlwaysON state is on the last rung with O:0.0 then it would always be active and the AlwaysOFF rung would be 
redundant.

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 3):

This completely depends on the vendor providing the ladder logic implementation.

Rockwell (and I'm sure some other vendors) RLL allows OTEs and other actions anywhere in a rung.  The output is controlled by the logic condition it is fed;  it also (at least, OTEs) passes that value further in the rung unchanged to be processed by more of the rung.

It is a nice style to have only one output per rung.   It is more efficient code-wise (and time wise) to have more than one output per rung, because the outputs can share the rung condition.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using ladder(LAD), just like  what T.Nesset said-

```
AlwaysON       O:0.0
---[]-------------()

AlwaysOFF      O:0.0
---[]-------------()
```

Q0.0 will turn "OFF" because PLC is scanning the program from then top to end.if you change a little bit just like this:

```
AlwaysOFF       O:0.0
---[]-------------()

AlwaysON        O:0.0
---[]-------------()
```

The result of Q0.0 will be "ON".
In Mitsubishi programming software just like GXWorks2, while you created the ladder program in this style, you will get a warning after complied. In Japanese the name of this style is "double coil".

If you would like to use in this style, please insert a jump instruction to separate these network/ separate in difference blocks and make sure only one block is running in each time.

Sorry for my poorly english.

Answer (score 0):

I have very often seen two parallel outputs in one rung. This would be logical if two outputs shared all but one input condition, for example, with the different input condition leading to two different outputs.

```
  I:0.00  I:0.01  I:0.02  O:1.00
---[/]-----[ ]-----[ ]-----O---
               |           
               |  I:0.03  O:1.01     
                ---[ ]-----O---
```

If two output conditions have completely different logic branches, though, it would not make sense to put them in the same rung. In fact, some vendors (Omron CX-One, for example) will not allow disconnected branches to be placed in the same rung.

Perhaps, as @franji1 mentioned in his comment, your professor was referring to putting the *same* output in more than one rung.